# Dynamic query ORM Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Alright I have a GeneralModel written in `CodeIgniter` and a friend asked me if I could convert it into `Laravel 4.2` for him. I was working on this and I think I have most of it correct but I am getting stuck at the select statement.

In `CodeIgniter` I have the following:

```
public function getData($table, $multiple = 1, $field = FALSE, $val = FALSE){

    if($field != FALSE){
        // WHERE in case of FIELD / VAL :)
        $this->db->where($field, $val);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get($table);

    if($multiple == 1){
        // Multiple rows
        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        // One row
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

Does anyone here knows how I can convert this function into `Laravel 4.2` syntax? 
I currently have:

```
public function getData($table, $multiple = 1, $field = FALSE, $val = FALSE){
    $result = DB::table($table);

}
```

I got stuck pretty quickly since I have no idea how I can achieve the same in `Laravel 4.2` with splitting up the sections of the `query` like I did with `CodeIgniter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain methods in the same way:

```
public function getData($table, $multiple = 1, $field = FALSE, $val = FALSE)
{
    $query = DB::table($table);

    if ($field != FALSE) {
        // WHERE in case of FIELD / VAL :)
        $query->where($field, $val);
    }

    if ($multiple)
        return $query->get();
    else
        return $query->first();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick awnser! Had no time to ask him if this worked for him but it looks pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel is similar in that you can use the [Fluent Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries) to build your queries in multiple stages prior to actually making the query. Once you know this, the translation is pretty straightforward:

```
public function getData($table, $multiple = 1, $field = FALSE, $val = FALSE)
{
    $query = DB::table($table);

    if($field){
        // WHERE in case of FIELD / VAL :)
        $query = $query->where($field, $val);
    }

    if($multiple) {
        return $query->get();
    }

    return $query->first();
}
```

I don't think it's really good practice relying on Fluent though inside of an Eloquent model, but there are cases where that can't be helped.  If the current objective is to convert the project to Laravel, there's probably calling code relying on the fact that this method exists.  Converting the function to use Eloquent rather than Fluent will change the function's signature and cause other parts of the code to break, but it would look like this:

```
public function getData($multiple = true, $field = false, $val = false)
{
    $query = $this;

    if($field) {
        $query = $query->where($field, $val);
    }

    if($multiple) {
        return $query->get();
    }

    return $query->first();
}
```

The calling code itself can be modified to do the exact same function in Laravel like this:

```
// Instead of...
$result = $model->getData(1, 'field', 'value');

// You can do this:
$result = $model->where('field', 'value')->get();

// Or this if you'd rather not have multiple:
$result = $model->where('field', 'value')->first();
```

Using this function inside Eloquent (IMHO) in the long run doesn't really save you much, and instead is mostly just clutter.

Comment: Thank you for the awnser, the main reason for the generalmodel is for a quick access to basic queries which will always be checked / validated before the actual use. It's just that a friend of mine isn't all into backend programming but needed a quick and easy way to call some basic queries (insert, select, count, update and delete) on single tables. Since I use a generalmodel myself with pre-validations before calling the query I thought it would be the best for him to use something simulair.